# Is there a best-practice way to implement a Python script that handles Windows and Linux environments differently?

Tags: python, linux, windows

Apologies if this has been answered on here before, but I did some searching and was unable to find an answer.

I'm taking over a Python application that runs on a remote Linux box, but need to do development locally on Windows. Naturally, I want the code I develop locally to match what gets deployed in production, but there are sections of the code that need to be handled differently between environments (due to library dependencies and OS minutiae).

Right now I'm simply handling this via `if` statements and `sys.platform` like the following:

`if platform == "linux"`

and this works but seems to me like there would be a better way to implement it.

Is there a more canonical or fault-tolerant way to do this?

Comment: Looks already good.

Comment: (this may be opinion based)

Answer (score 0):

The `if` is okay but don't litter that all over the code but try to isolate an API.  See for instance how the `os` module handles importing the appropriate platform dependent path module.